# Addressing from the root directory of website in action script

Tags: asp.net, flash, actionscript, web, action

I have a flash banner in my website and it has some navigation links on it .

Because I have several different folders in my website I need address them from the root .

At the moment i use getUrl like this :

getURL("ArticleList/Default.aspx");

But it doesn't work .
Thanks in advance

Comment: You really shouldn't be putting your navigation in a Flash banner...

Answer (score 0):

Try using ~/Folder/Page.aspx. ~ signifies root in ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

You can use the base parameter while embedding the Flash movie. All relative paths inside the movie are resolved according to that. Have a look at it here - http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/127/tn_12701.html